# Count each value on button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I try to count each value in each button

[image: This is the example]

The PHP Code

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){?>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-count" data-id="<?php echo($i)?>" id="click[<?php echo($i)?>]"> 
Click Me <h7 id="count[<?php echo($i)?>]">(0)</h7>
</a>
<?php }?>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $(".btn-count").click(function(){
     i++;
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     $("#count["+id+"]").text(i);
  });
}
```

But it didn't work at all. Anyone can tell me where this code goes wrong?

Comment: Javascript and Jquery is frontend and PHP is backend. Are you trying to count these values on the browser?

Comment: *didn't work at all* - so you just see a blank page?  That would still be *something*.  What do you get?  What do you not get?   Have you tried debugging your click handler? (basic: add a `console.log(i)`)

Comment: Check the browser console for errors (F12, select console) - your code, *as provided*, is missing `)` at the end - this may be the cause of your issues or may just be a copy+paste into the SO question issue.

Comment: @freedomn-m for console.log(i) I already tried it and it increase each time I click

Comment: @nice_dev yeah is it wrong ?

Comment: @MarchelGunawanDwiSteya I think Nice_dev was confused about if you wanted to count the value in front end or backend. I Think it's faily easy to see that you are using jquery to do the counter.

Comment: Your issue is that `$("#count["+id+"]")` is `#count[1]` which means: find element with id=count *and* has *attribute* of "1" - which makes no sense.  Should be `$("#count"+id)`  https://jsfiddle.net/ngzrpvey/   Having said that you probably don't want to use *semantic IDs* and instead use `data-id` on the destination to link them:  `<h7 data-count-id="2">` + `$("[data-count-id='" + id + "']")` - but that's only any use if they are in different areas of the document - as the count is nested in the button, just use `$(this).find("h7")` (as per provided answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the id's for this, you can use `.find()` to find the child based on your html.

Then get the "count" value from your element and add 1 to it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-count").click(function() {
    $(this).find("h6").text(function(i, n) {
      var count = +n.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1];
      return `(${count+1})`
    });
  });
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-count").click(function() {
    $(this).find("h6").text(function(i, n) {
      var count = +n.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1];
      return `(${count+1})`
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-count" data-id="<?php echo($i)?>" id="click[<?php echo($i)?>]"> 
Click Me <h6 id="count[<?php echo($i)?>]">(0)</h6>
</a>


<a class="btn btn-primary btn-count" data-id="<?php echo($i)?>" id="click[<?php echo($i)?>]"> 
Click Me <h6 id="count[<?php echo($i)?>]">(0)</h6>
</a>
```

Problem with having a global counter as you have in `var i = 0;` it will no represent the button you have click, but all of them.

Comment: As an addition: rather than parse the output text, you can store the current count in the data of the button/h6.

Comment: @freedomn-m True, that could be a way to do it also

Answer (score 1):

your code can be simply modified to this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-count" data-id="1" id="click1"> 
Click Me <h7 id="count1">(0)</h7>
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-count" data-id="2" id="click2"> 
Click Me <h7 id="count2">(0)</h7>
</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".btn-count").click(function(){ 
     var id = $(this).data('id');
    var value = $(this).data('value');
    value++
    $(this).data('value', value);
    console.log(id)
    console.log( $("#count"+id))
     $("#count"+id).text(value);
  });
})
```

Here is also a demo for the code

https://codepen.io/BubuKiki/pen/YzegWMg

The problem is with the special characters, it does not seem to find them.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Try and click on each of them once, then you can see that one says count 1 and the other says count 2, I believe both should say 1, because you have only clicked once

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen that is true, ill edit it right now